# Chart in Sharepoint, No Code

Tags: custom-list, chart-web-part

I have below data in custom list

```
State
A1
A1
A1
A2
A2
A3
```

Can I create below type of chart in Sharepoint 2010 where x axis is state and y axis is state occurrence.

[image]

Comment: You can export to excel a list data and generate a chart with excel. If required, you can use the Excel Viewer web part to push on a web page this chart.

Comment: No, not without code or additional services. The most straightforward way is, and I agree with Steve B, turn on Excel Services and load a static Excel Services webpart. This will require no-code, no-third party software, and minor configuration (if your list is in a XLSX file.) The second option is SSRS (for no code). g'luck. (Oh, on note about Excel Services: it requires Enterprise CALs.)

Comment: :( It looks complicated..

Comment: If you are willing to make State a lookup (A new list holding only the states) you can count occurrences its used in your current list